# Firefox opens multiple and sometimes duplicate tabs when closing tabs and opening links?

Tags: firefox, mouse

I don't think this could be Firefox itself but it is the only software that seems to have an issue. It seems that when I open a link into a new tab *sometimes* two of the links are opened, also *sometimes* when opening new tabs with the `+` button two blank tabs are opened. It also seems when closing tabs *sometimes* a new empty tab is opened.

I am not sure what to make of this or what other information I could offer. I have used Chrome for a few days and have not noticed the same issue so I don't think that it has to do with the mouse, but maybe?

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** This seems to be getting weirder. Another issue I have started noticing is that after using the computer for about ~4 hours and having multiple windows and tabs opened in Firefox the mouse movement is very laggy and unresponsive at times. When I close Firefox the mouse seems to be magically fixed.

Is my mouse going bad?...

Comment: Your mouse is sending double clicks occasionally instead of single clicks?

Comment: That was my original idea but after some testing it doesn't seem to be. I'm actually firing up a small WinForms application to see what it reports for OnMouseClick events